# Show all the Print inside a loop Python

Tags: python

I have a print inside a loop, everything goes fine: I can see all.

```
 for in range(0,10000) :
     function_using_show()
     print 25)
```

But, When I put the same code inside a function :

```
def ff() :
  for in range(0,10000) :
     function_using_show()
     print 25

def function_using_show():
     plt.plot(X,Y)
     plt.show()
```

Only the last graph and the last '25' is printed.
How to show all the graphs and print when the loop is inside a function ?

Edited

Comment: There's not enough context here. Please show how you generate the plots.

Comment: can you update the code of your show() function..

Comment: Does the print you're talking about is "25"?

Comment: The Graph and the 25

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the : at the end of the if statement

Comment: You should write that as a comment. And also I think this is not the case because otherwise the given code would not have compiled and print anything, So, this is just a small mistake in the post.

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is that you try to perform `plt.show()` in a loop, but the thing you are not considering here is that **this method is blocking**: 
quoting the [tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html): 
 
*"Because this mainloop is blocking by default (**i.e., script execution is paused**), you should only call this once per script, at the end. Script execution is resumed after the last window is closed. Therefore, if you are using matplotlib to generate only images and do not want a user interface window, you do not need to call show"* 
The solution is to show all your plots in the same window, for example (taken from here):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(t):
    return np.exp(-t) * np.cos(2*np.pi*t)

t1 = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.1)
t2 = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.02)

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(t1, f(t1), 'bo', t2, f(t2), 'k')

plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(t2, np.cos(2*np.pi*t2), 'r--')
plt.show()
```

> output:

[image]

Comment: Cf My EDITED version.
in fact, without a function, it works well.